# Can you safely use a std::set as the key to a std::map?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have defined the following:

```
typedef std::set<std::string> entry;
typedef std::map<entry, size_t> freq_map;
```

In this way, I can read in lines from a text file of this form and keep track of each sets frequency:

```
A;B;C
C;B;A
A;B
```

In my first scenario I am to create a frequency map of only cardinality one sets

```
void Apriori::populate_length_one_freq() {
    freq_map length_one_map;
    for (const auto& s : some_data_structure) {
        entry tmp = { s };
        add_to_map(tmp, length_one_map, 1);
    }
    prune_map(length_one_map, 700);
    freq.push_back(length_one_map);
}

void Apriori::add_to_map(entry& en, freq_map& map, size_t ct) {
    auto search = map.find(en);
    if (search != map.end()) {
        map.at(en) += ct;
    } else {
        map.emplace(en, ct);
    }   
}

void Apriori::prune_map(freq_map& m, const size_t cut) {
    for (auto& item : m) {
        if (item.second < cut) {
            m.erase(item.first);
        }
    }
}
```

This almost works. I am running into an odd bug, however. Certain items do not seem to be getting iterated over in the prune_map function. I can verify this by printing each value to std out while iterating. For example, the item {"Airports"} is not being printed. Strangely, when I do a m.find() of the Airports item in the function, the item is found. See below code:

```
void Apriori::prune_map(freq_map& m, const size_t cut) {
    std::set<std::string> f = {"Airports"};
    if (m.find(f) != m.end()) {
        std::cout << "found." << std::endl;
    }

    for (auto& item : m) {
        for (auto& s : item.first) {
            std::cout << s << std::endl;
        }
        if (item.second < cut) {
            m.erase(item.first);
        }
    }
}
```

What could cause my iteration to fail?

Comment: The answer to your titular question: Yes. For us to be able to help you, create a [mcve]

Comment: Pretty sure erasing invalidates the current terator.  A range based loop is not what you want here since you need to assign the value erase returns to your iterator and in that case you do not want to increment it for that iteration of the loop.

Comment: That was the cause of my problem. Thank you